# Is it possible to hibernate Ubuntu and then resume Ubuntu in a VM (and then the other way around)?

Tags: dual-boot, games, hibernate

I'm trying to find ways of solving my need to play games which run only on windows and which WINE does not support.
I've been trying PCI pass-through but it doesn't work for the setup I want to use (see [this guide](https://gist.github.com/Misairu-G/616f7b2756c488148b7309addc940b28) for my source) I'm currently stuck at trying to boot from the "CD".

As one of the ways, it would be to run Ubuntu as my main OS, then when wanting to play a game, switching to windows (as hibernated dual-boot) and then resume Ubuntu using a hypervisor (vmware probably) and then being able to play the game I want while continuing to have all the programs I normally use (E.g. IRC chat) and my dev web server (Apache web server) resuming after the switch. This would allow me to have my Ubuntu working while I am playing the windows exclusive games I want.

So far I could actually find this: https://www.vmware.com/pdf/dualboot_tech_note.pdf
If I understood it right, it allows running dual-boot the way I want, for as long as I don't mount the other one's used mounts. The only detail here I would have to deal with to be that I do have to shut down the OS and reboot it. I wouldn't be able to hibernate.

For as long as VMware can handle passing (such as DirectX 10), I also may just run windows on the VM instead (mostly slightly older games, for what I understood).

Am I missing anything? Does it require that much digging and waiting so one can play games which are made for windows?

Comment: Have you thought about running Windows in VirtualBox? Then you don't have to hibernate Ubuntu.

Comment: @jpezz VirtualBox does not support 3D rendering to the complexity level that games require.